# How to express "A mod (B-C)" in terms of "A mod B" and "A mod C"

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have a fraction of the type $\frac{A}{B-C}$ and would like to know when this is an integer. Let us suppose that you can calculate A $mod$ B as well as A $mod$ C quite easily, however A $mod$ (B-C) is not obvious. I would like to "disentagle" the difference from the modular operation.

Is there a way to express A $mod$ (B-C) in terms of A $mod$ B and A $mod$ C such there the term $B-C$ does not appear anymore? Even if it is an ugly term with multiple mods, it would be quite helpful.

Comment: No, there isn't.  Suppose $A\equiv 0 \pmod 5$ and $A\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.  Then $A$ might be $15$ or $30$ (for example).  One of them is odd and one of them is even.

Comment: Hint: by CRT: knowing $\,a\bmod b\,$ and $\,a\bmod c\,$ is equivalent to knowing $\,a\bmod \ell,\,$ for $\, \ell = {\rm lcm(b,c)},\,$ and from $\,a\bmod \ell\,$ we can uniquely determine $\,a\bmod n\iff n\mid \ell,\,$ so  you need $\,B-C\mid {\rm lcm}(B,C)\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way, i.e., you cannot calculate $A \pmod {(B-C)}$ given only $A \pmod B$ and $A \pmod C$.

Take $A =2^5$. Then on the one hand take $B=2^4$ and $C=2^3$, then $A \pmod B =A \pmod C=0$. What is $A \pmod {(B-C)}$ here. On the other hand, take $B=2^4$ and $C=4$. Then here as well $A \pmod B=A \pmod C=0$. But now what is $A \pmod {(B-C)}$.